# add data layer from mxd table of contents in custom arcmap toolbox

Tags: arcmap

Can't find any references for how to add a data layer into a custom toolbox that I made in ArcMap via a dropdown menu instead of navigating to the file location.

The first picture is what the input for my tool lookslike, and the second is a screen shot of the Clip tool which has the dropdown options.

[image: my tool- no dropdown option for input file]

[image: clip tool with dropdown]

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the **parameter type** in the script input parameters. This cannot be controlled in the script that you created, but has to be done in the tool (within ArcMap).

For this specific case, I believe `Feature Class` is the parameter type that you want (if not, `Feature Layer` -- I honestly haven't done this in ages, and there are quite a few  options!)

You can also set options such as whether or not the parameter is required.

See Esri help pages for full details: [Setting script tool parameters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/setting-script-tool-parameters.htm) and [Understanding script tool parameters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/understanding-script-tool-parameters.htm).